# Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Restaurant.Data.IAppRepository

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPGej.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp66o.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxTDo.png)

Hello, I'm getting this error, I don't understand why

Comment: Please do not post code as images, code is usually text - so post it as text. The same goes for errors.

Comment: Also please read [ask] and take a [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering `DbContext` but resolving `DbContexts`. Change registration to:

```cs
builder.AddDbContext<DbContexts>(...)
```

To prevent such typos from happening give your contexts meaningful names (and all classes in general). At least `AppDbContext` but better something like `RestaurantDbContext` or something related to domain that this context will represent/store.